# Copying an instance of a singleton to store in array

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton

I would like to take a singleton class that gets used by multiple view controllers, copy it, and save it to an array that will be displayed in another view controller with a table view that will show multiple instances of that class. This array will eventually be archived to be retrieve with the same data.

Before I attempt this, is there a way I can duplicate this singleton instance, save it to the array, re-initialize it for the next use, and so on (without getting the same exact previously uninitialized object)?

Comment: What you are describing is contrary to the definition of a singleton. It's at best a "multipleton". If you want several instances of a class, simply instantiate them and set them up appropriately. Otherwise, please expand your question, perhaps with some applicable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a singleton that you want.
A singleton `must always` return the `same instance`.
What you want is a normal class that maybe have a convenience class method to feed you some pre-populated object.

If it's possible to create more than one instance of an object it's not a singleton anymore.

But your singleton class could hold a variable amount of instance of other class that you wish to display.
So in that way what you are asking could be possible, but without the copy part on the singleton.

---

> I'm not sure where you are going with this and if it's the best way to
>   go but here is an idea :

you can have a `singleton` class that would hold an array of an other class. So you could call your `singleton` like this

```
TheSingletonClassName *mySingleton = [TheSingletonClassName sharedTheSingletonClassName];
OtherClass *myOtherClass = [mySingleton newOtherClassInstancePlease];
```

In your `newOtherClassInstancePlease` method you implement the necessary thing to store that new object into an array, that you can distribute like this

```
NSArray *otherClassArray = [mySingleton allOtherClasses];
```

Or NSMutableArray if you prefer.

With that you would be able to share, create new and even delete object. if you implement the necessary method on your singleton.
But again don't copy a singleton, if the singleton is well implemented sending it a copy call should throw an exception, or return the single singleton instance that exists.

Comment: If its no longer singleton, then ill have to instantiate a new instance of the same class for each view controller, right? With that, the instances wouldn't be the same, so the data would also not transfer over, correct? How would this convenience method work? Thanks for the quick reply  :-)

Comment: Maybe I can setup an NSMutableArray in the singleton class and pass that around? Have a global variable that references the size of the array where it will work off the last object on the array till it is saved. Is that worth trying?

Comment: you don't need a global variable to hold down the size of an NSArray, you just need to ask it `- (NSUInteger)count` as if you want the last object of an NSArray, still you just ask it `- (id)lastObject` Look at the NSArray reference for more detail about them.

Comment: So a singleton class with an array that can be passed around all view controllers containing as many instances of a custom data class which can be accessed with array methods... I think this will work. Thank you for the idea.                                                                     **Can someone please vote this up, as I am unable to at my membership status**

Comment: @Chuck for the convenience thing, I was thinking something like when you do [NSString StringWithString:@"some String"]; Those class method are call by Apple Convenience method because they return autorelease object. So I use it in that sense. (Thanks for correcting that horrible auto-correct suggestion bad choice)